# How to reinitialize session in Hibernate with thread context?

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, session, session-management

Note: This question is related for my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723596/spring-hibernate-session-management-across-multiple-threads).

I am using `hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread` in my Hibernate configuration and getting Hibernate sessions via `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` as needed. So it does create or give me existing sessions when needed, so I do not take care of this.

This is all great, but what to do when I do get a `HibernateException`, a `ConstraintViolationException` for example? Then the current session I acquired before becomes invalid and I cannot use it anymore, not even for reading out some more data (according to many forums I've read). How can I discard and get then the new session within particular scope? I think calling `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` for the 2nd time still will return me the same invalid session!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [`ThreadLocalSessionContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html), the session will be closed when the transaction finsihes.  So in this case you should call `tx.rollback()`, then `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to start afresh.